# Create text in query builder, select

Tags: cakephp-3.8

I need to add text in Query builder select.

```
SELECT '5 a 8 lugares' as 'lugares', count(*) AS 'livres' FROM salas S;
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem

```
$lugares_3_4->select(['lugar' => $lugares_3_4->func()->concat(['3 a 4 
lugares']),'livres'=>'count(Salas.id)'])
```